# MSVS 2015 getline() function does not work? (C++)

Tags: c++

Error:identifier "getline" is undefined. What am I overlooking?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string str;
getline(cin, str);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Include the right header file. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
#include <string>
```

to be able to use `std::string` and `std::getline()`. Without that even the line

```
string str;
```

will most likely produce a compiler error.

Comment: alright that works but I also had to change getch() to _getch

Comment: @LukeWeaver, `getch()` is a non-standard function. I don't use it at all and can't comment on it. I am glad you figured out what works.